# Delete hanging ferret index entry after record deleted

Tags: ruby, ferret, acts-as-ferret

I'm using ActsAsFerret which is a Rails wrapper for the Ruby-based [Ferret](https://github.com/yieldbot/ferret) search engine.

Sometimes it seems a record is deleted using SQL, rather than via ActiveRecord (ie record.destroy), and when this happens an index entry is left in the Ferret index.

I can see it in this example, where School #136574 has left a hanging index entry:  In the search below I'm using the `lazy` option, which says "Just get the data out of the Ferret index and don't bother hitting the database":

```
>> @schools = School.search(params)
=> [#<FerretResult wrapper for School with id 136574, #<FerretResult wrapper for School with id 55814]
>> @schools.collect(&:id)
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find School with ID=136574
```

This causes a serious problem because if you try and do anything with the results it does School.find(id) and you get an exception like above.

I did `School.rebuild_index`, thinking that would fix it, but it hasn't.

I **can** work around it - it seems that calling `.collect` on the results has been overridden to convert them into their corresponding object (causing the exception), and I can do something like this:

```
@schools = @schools.select{|result| School.find_by_id(result.id)};@schools.size
```

This does work, but it's slow, and a bit of a pain in the ass.

Does anyone know a way to delete the hanging index records?